# How to display child page from specific parent page in homepage?

Tags: pages

How to display child page from specific parent page in homepage ?

This is my page structure

```
Home
About Us
Hotel Category
  Hotel A
    Room 1
    Room 2
  Hotel B
    Room 1
    Room 2
  Hotel C
    Room 1
    Room 2
Contact Us
```

And i try to achieve this at homepage(parent page is Hotel Category : id=8)

```
Hotel A
Hotel B
Hotel C
```

List Hotel A, Hotel B and Hotel C with some except and thumbnail image(this magic field)

Comment: Try this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-posts/). You can use it in your sidebar(as widget) and set which posts you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
<?php
  $pages = get_pages('child_of=199');
  foreach($pages as $child) {
?>
  <h3><?php echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?></h3> 
<?php 
  // This next line gets the full page of content
  // echo get_post_field('post_content', $child->ID);

 // This next line will cut the content off at 450 letters
  // With a read more link under it 
  echo '<p>' . substr(get_post_field('post_content', $child->ID), 0, 450) . '</p>'; ?> 
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $child->ID ); ?>"> READ MORE </a> 
<?php } ?>
```

---

Change "child_of=199" with the ID of the page you want to get the children of.

There is a line that is commented out, that line will get the full page of content

The line that is being used to get content will only get the first 450 letters.

---

There has to be a better way to get content, as this pulls in the HTML and all - so if that first 450 letter happens to land in the middle of a image you will have broken text.

I am sure a quick google search of "get post content by Id" should help with that part

Answer (score 0):

Below code (Template for show child pages with title and excerpt) might useful to you. if you are using wordpress  category->post instead of worpdress page, change the wp_query accordingly. You can get more information about wp_query : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Here's the template code:

`<?php
  /**
  Template Name: show child pages
  */
  get_header(); ?>

          <div id="container">
              <div id="content" role="main">

              <?php
                  get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' );
                  global $post;

                  $args=array(
                  "post_parent" => $post->ID,
                  'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'page' ),
                  'post_type' => 'page'
                  );
                  // The Query
                  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                  // The Loop
                  echo "<ul>";
                  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                      echo '<li class="chiled-title">';
                              the_title();
                          the_excerpt();
                      echo '</li>';

                  endwhile;
                  echo "<ul/>";
                 ?>
            <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                  <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                      <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                      <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                  </div><!-- #nav-below -->
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php
                  // Reset Post Data
                  wp_reset_postdata();
              ?>

              </div><!-- #content -->
          </div><!-- #container -->

  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>`